# how to return a structure (defined in .h file) from a function in another cpp file?

Tags: function, structure

I ran into this issue and I cannot handle it. Any suggestion is appreciated.
I have a structure defined in a header file as follows:
Results.h

```
#ifndef RESULTS_H
#define RESULTS_H

struct Results
{
    double dOptSizeMWh;
    double dOrigSOCFinal;
    double dManiSOCFinal;
};

#endif
```

and a general definition of "Deterministic" function in Deterministic.h:

```
#ifndef DETERMINISTIC_H
#define DETERMINISTIC_H

Results Deterministic(int,int,int,double,double); //Deterministic(int nNoMonth, int nNOWind, int nWindLength, double dPreviousSizeMWh, double dPreviousSOC)
#endif;
```

This function is implemented in Deterministic.cpp:

```
#include "Results.h"
Results Deterministic(int nNoMonth, int nNOWind, int nWindLength, double dPreviousSizeMWh, double dPreviousSOC)
{
    // returns number of rows and columns of the array created
    struct Results sRes;
    sRes.dOptSizeMWh   = -1.0;  // for the optimal size of battery in MWh
    sRes.dOrigSOCFinal = -1.0;  // for the SOC at the end of the window
    sRes.dManiSOCFinal = -1.0;  // this is set to 0.0 if final SOC is slightly below 0
    //...........................////
    // OTHER Calculation .......////
    //...........................////
    return sRes;
 }
```

Finally, I have a main file which I call Deterministic function and I use Results structure, main.cpp:

```
#include <Results.h>
#include <Deterministic.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int nNoMonth    = 1;    // the month that we want to use in the input
    int nWindLength = 1;    // length of window, hour
    int nNODays     = 1;    // number of days that we want to repeat optimization
    struct Results dValues;
    double **mRes = new double*[nNODays * 24 / nWindLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < nNODays * 24 / nWindLength; ++i) mRes[i] = new double[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < nNODays * 24 / nWindLength; i++)
    {
         if (i == 0) 
         {
             dValues = Deterministic(nNoMonth, i, nWindLength, 0.0, 0.0);
         }else
         {
             temp0 = *(*(mRes+i-1)); double temp1 = *(*(mRes+i-1)+1); double temp2 = *(*(mRes+i-1)+2); 

             if (temp2 == -1.0) {dValues = Deterministic(nNoMonth, i, nWindLength, temp0, temp1);}
             else {dValues = Deterministic(nNoMonth, i, nWindLength, *(*(mRes+i-1)), *(*(mRes+i-1)));}
        }

        *(*(mRes+i)) = dValues.dOptSizeMWh;
        *(*(mRes+i)+1) = dValues.dOrigSOCFinal;
        *(*(mRes+i)+2) = dValues.dManiSOCFinal;
  }
```

these are only a small portion of the codes in Deterministic.cpp and main.cpp which defines the problem. First loop goes well (i.e., i=0) without any problem, but it fails in the second loop and beyond with this error: "R6010 - abort() has been called"
This error comes up in the main.cpp where I call Deterministic function in the if statement.

Comment: Use a debugger to investigate the crash.

Comment: Andrew, Thanks for your response. I tried but it doesn't specifically tells the root cause

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem compiling and running the posted code (other than the missing `double` in front of the declaration of `temp`).  Without knowing what `Deterministic()` is *actually* doing, it's a bit hard to guess what the problem is (divide by zero? playing a Justin Bieber mp3?).  It shouldn't have anything to do with returning a structure from a function defined in another file (translation units are a fundamental feature of the language).  To find the root cause, single-step through the (complete) `Deterministic()` using your debugger.

Comment: thanks but it fails when I call Deterministic right away. it doesn't go through the code in Deterministic at all so that I would be able to debug it.

Comment: ok I got it. I found the error in the code in Deterministic as you said. Appreciate your help.